# What is the simplest language which support template&context mechanism?

Tags: python, django, templates, programming-languages, django-context

I need to find the easiest way to automatically build ebooks from downloaded articles.

I want to automatically generate TOC, which will be based on HTML template.

I know that python django has template & context mechanism, however django is a little to complicated for people to which I am preparing this whole mechanism. I don't need all web-related features.

Comment: I think you mean framework (in your question title) instead of language. Python is a computer language, Django is a framework written in Python.

Comment: @Paulo Scardine: I guess that some programming language can has this as native mechanism. Otherwise simple framework will be equally good.

Comment: I think you can call PHP a template oriented language, for that sake, although IMHO PHP demands a lot more discipline to write clean and maintainable code compared to Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO, if you are familiar with Django:

- if you want to build a command line application or a abstract library, look at [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/) template engine.
- if you are looking for a web framework simpler than Django, look at [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/) (Flask uses Jinja2 as the default template engine).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build command line application, for people that don't know django template engine - dive deeper into [`markdown`](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/). It has some [libraries](http://freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown/) around, hope you will find what you need.